# Split integer into separate parts

Tags: java, numbers, integer

I am at the beginning of programming and I need help with this.
How can I turn integer number 123 into

```
1
2
3
```

into **separate lines** if you understand me? Thanks

Comment: Hint: Convert the int into the a String and then iterate through each character in te String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two steps to achieve that are

- `split` to have each digit separatly
- print each on a new line

---

*Classic* :

```
int foo = 123;
String[] split = (foo+"").split("");
for(int i=0; i<split.length; i++)
    System.out.println(split[i]);
```

*Shorter* :

```
int foo = 123;
Arrays.asList((foo+"").split("")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Instead of foo+"" I recommend String.valueOf().  Instead of using split, you can simply using .toCharArray.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 - do all calculations using integers

```
    int d = 123;
    int d1 = d % 10;
    int d2 = (d / 10) % 10;
    int d3 = (d / 100);
```

Solution 2 - Convert to string and use `charAt`

```
    int d = 123;
    String str = Integer.toString(d);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
int number = 123;

while (number > 0) {
    System.out.println( number % 10);
    number = number / 10;
}
```

Comment: code only posts may answer the question, but leave open the *how* and *why* your snippet is the one that should be used, so please explain what you're actually doing, so this just doesn't get copy+pasted, but understood

Comment: this is imo the best answer as it does not converting and splitting strings which is a big overhead, but it is solely based on arithmetic ops. And it produces the desired output

Answer (score -3):

That should do it, but I didn't test it :

```
int a = 123;
int a1 = a % 10; // -> 3
int a2 = (a - a1)/10 % 10; // -> 2
int a3 = (a - a2*10 - a1)/100 % 10; // -> 1
```

Comment: So you say his case is not specific ?

Comment: maybe it's an example no ? ;) and even if not, reuse `a` and `123` ^^

Comment: How can it not be case-specific if it has only 3 outputs?

Comment: @MarkoZajc what about OP just took 3 as an example, but has to split a number like `1934852349` into every digit and print those out

Comment: I think that from my example, you can easily guess a `n` case, for example with an array. But I recognize it should have been a comment most than an answer

Comment: @Lino that's what I was talking about